# Medoo PHP Framework and joining multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, join, medoo

Trying to join 3 tables: leagues, leagues_teams, and teams.

With the query:

```
$teams = $database->select(
    'teams',
    [
    '[>]leagues_teams' =>
        [
            'fifa_id' => 'fifa_team_id'
        ],
        '[>]leagues' =>
        [
            'fifa_league_id' => 'fifa_id'
        ]
    ], [
        'teams.fifa_id',
        'teams.name',
        'teams.rating'
    ], [
        'ORDER' => 'teams.name ASC'
    ]
);
```

Which results in the following query:

```
SELECT "teams"."fifa_id","teams"."name","teams"."rating"
FROM "teams"
LEFT JOIN "leagues_teams" ON "teams"."fifa_id" = "leagues_teams"."fifa_team_id"
LEFT JOIN "leagues" ON "teams"."fifa_league_id" = "leagues"."fifa_id"
ORDER BY "teams"."name" ASC
```

When adding the second *LEFT JOIN*, it should join with *leagues_teams.fifa_league_id=leagues.fifa_id* and not *teams.fifa_league_id*

How would I go about this join?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone was still having this problem, from MEDOO documentation:

> You can refer the previous joined table by adding the table name before the column.

Example:

`"[>]album" => ["account.user_id" => "user_id"],`

[MEDOO - SELECT API](http://medoo.in/api/select)